# Объясните мне кто -нибудь, для чего нужен AppCompatButton?

Tags: android

Вот зачем нужен AppCompatButton если есть Button. Какой смысл использовать AppCompatButton Который все равно не поддерживает Tint до 21 API.

Comment: Из [описания класса](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html) в офф.документации что то не понятно?

Comment: @pavlofff, А то что это все ерунда. Ничего не работает. Я попробовал AppCompactButton backgroundTint на 23 и выше работает, меньше 21 не работает. Через XML менял. И не я первый кто такое темы создает. 

Зачем они лгут разработчикам я не понимаю

Comment: Ну, если вы будете использовать AppCompactButton то на устройствах 23 и выше в вашей программе backgroundTint будет работать, а на устройствах меньше, не будет. В то же время, если вы будете использовать просто Button то вы вообще не сможете задать backgroundTint, и у вас оно не будет работать ни на старых ни на новых устройствах.